# Reactjs screen is not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, render, screen

**I think that the problem is in the switch, in version of react-router-dom or in routes. Only when I created and applied the code in this class, the screen started don't render and stays white. I already changed the version of react-router-dom but I don't know what can be.**
**Below the code of routes.js:**

```
//react-router-dom version: "^5.3.0"
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Header from './components/Header';

const Routes = () => {
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Header/>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default Routes;
```

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: If you are using the new version of react-router, instead of componente you should use element={Home}

Comment: I don't see the errors either, but the problem started in this class, now the localhost is with a white screen loading infinitely and no error message, and the project has other files like the header in js and css that was supposed to show

Comment: With the new version do I need to remove the switch from there?

Answer (score 0):

React Router v6 introduces some changes like.

**Routes** component that is kind of like Switch, but a lot more powerful one.

**Route** still exist but you don't pass a pointer to that component function or as a children component, Instead you pass the JSX element to the element prop &
**exact** doesn't exist anymore, now it's always looks for exact matches.

So, ***component={Home}** would become **element={<Home />}***

Something like this

```js
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
</Routes>
```

You can dive deep to this migration guide: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5

hope that's help you